# Google Play Console Error notification 'Device Support Removed'

Tags: android, google-play-console

I got error `notification` when trying to upload / update new APK to Google Play Console, I've no idea what it is.

It's like my newer `APK` version is supporting fewer Device than my old `APK`. But I'm sure nothing changed in manifest file, it's only fix-bug update

[image: Device Support Removed]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this error or figured out what the impact is?

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps because you changed the supported API in your app. Re-check it again to make sure that the supported API is the same as the one in your previous version. That notification is NOT an error, it is a warning notification to let you know that your app will support fewer types of devices than it does before.

For example, your previous version supports API from 15, but your newer version only supports API from 16.